# Creating a layout in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to translate a design from a designer into html/css using bootstrap but I'm struggling to get it to work. Each square will be a different image, but for now I've just been playing with divs with borders.

When on a mobile device each image should be in a single column - so it seems like they should be `col-xs-12`.

Any idea how I should replicate this using bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: "struggling to get it to work" - I would suggest posting a version of what you have, with maybe a screenshot of what it's currently doing. Otherwise, this is probably a bit too broad of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will struggle to replicate this kind of layout using bootstrap - The bootstrap grid works on a row based principle, that means your columns with fit nicely together horizontally, but not vertically - new elements will always clear the larger element above it which will leave gaps (I have attached an example of the BS issue).

You are much better off using something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve a layout like this.

```css
.one {
  background: yellow;
}
.two {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.three {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
.four {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class "row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 one">There is a gap under me above 768px width because div elements three and four will always clear the largest height of elements above.</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 two">two</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 three">three</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 four">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoa! Masonry looks awesome! A good portion of the site is very bootstrap friendly - elements in a row, etc. It's just this homepage and getting the heights to play well in a non-row that's been doing it. I'll definitely give Masonry a go though!

Comment: Yay! Good luck and enjoy masonry!

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `col-xs-12` to all div that you will be using and add the classes `col-md-x`, x could be a any number from 1 to 12.

For divs with 2 tiles in 1 column, add 2 divs with the `class col-md-6`

The height of the divs shall be set manually